# PHP Add numbers 1-10 and only even numbers 1-10. Display sums separately with one loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to use ONE PHP for loop to echo the sum of the numbers 1-10 as well as echo the sum of only the even numbers. I seem to have a problem as these iterations won't be "parallel"

Code:

```
<?php
    $sum = 0; $evensum = 0;
    for($x = 1, $y=2; $x<=10, $y<=6; $x++, $y += 2) {
    $sum = $sum + $x; $evensum = $evensum + $y;
        }
    echo "total sum= ". $sum, ", even sum=" . $evensum;  
?>
```

**total sum** should reflect **55** (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10) and **even sum** should reflect **30** (2+4+6+8+10)

Comment: There's no way that this is for a homework assignment with a username of `student_coder`...

Answer (score 4):

Just Use

```
<?php
    $sum = 0; $evensum = 0;
    for($x = 1; $x<=10; $x++) {
        // sum all the number
        $sum = $sum + $x;
        // check the number is even 
        if( $x % 2 === 0 ) { 
           // sum only the even numbers
           $evensum = $evensum + $x;
        }
    }
    // output
    echo "total sum= ". $sum, ", even sum=" . $evensum;  
?>
```

Comment: Why would the OP use this? An explanation is always welcome. With ~13k rep you should know that.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)  and [array_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

```
$arr=range(1,10);
echo $sum=array_sum($arr);

function even($var)
{

    return(!($var & 1));
}

echo $even=array_sum(array_filter($arr, "even"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum all ranges

```
$all_sum=array_sum(range(1,10));
```

Sum even number `(0,2,4,6,8,10)`

```
$even_sum = array_sum(range(0,10,2));
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer is only meant to copy-Paste its not helpful.